# Обновить XML-файл средствами QDomElement

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, qt4

Есть XML-файл со следующей структурой:

```
<xml>
 <tRequestResponse>
   <Name>...</Name>
   <Request>...</Request>
   <Response>...</Response>
   <Comment>...</Comment>
 </tRequestResponse>

...

 <tRequestResponse>
   <Name>...</Name>
   <Request>...</Request>
   <Response>...</Response>
   <Comment>...</Comment>
 </tRequestResponse>
</xml>
```

Ветка tRequestResponse повторяется в файле 4 раза. Мне нужно обновить данные в теге Response для второй ветки tRequestResponse. Как это сделать? По firstchild я попадаю только в первый tRequestResponse.

```
void MainWindow::TrNode(QDomElement root, QString tagname)
{

    QDomNodeList items = root.elementsByTagName(tagname);
    qDebug() << "Total items: " << items.count();
    for (int i = 0; i<items.count(); i++)
    {
        //qDebug() << items.count();
        QDomNode itemnode = items.at(i);
        if(itemnode.isElement())
        {
            QDomElement itemelem = itemnode.toElement();
            qDebug() << "elem is: " << itemelem.text();

            QString str;
            QTextStream stream(&str);
            //QTextEdit* txt = new QTextEdit();
            itemnode.firstChild().save(stream,0);
            //txt->setText(str);
            //txt->show();
            QString match = QString("024000150E00323031373039323231");
            if(!str.contains(match))
            {
                qDebug() << "er";
            }
            else
            {
                ui->textEdit->append(str);
            }
        }

    }

}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString FileName1 = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open", "C://", "*.txt*");
    QFile file(FileName1);
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        //QMessageBox::critical(this, "Eror", "Error MF", QMessageBox::Ok);
        qDebug() << "Error";

    }
    QTextStream in(&file);
    QString text = in.readAll();
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(text);
    file.close();

    //text = text.simplified();



}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString text = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
    text = text.simplified();
    text.replace(" ", "");
    qDebug() << text;
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(text);

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    QString FileName2 = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open", "C://", "*.xml*");
    QFile XMLfile(FileName2);
    QDomDocument domDoc;
    if (!XMLfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        //QMessageBox::critical(this, "Eror", "Error MF", QMessageBox::Ok);
        qDebug() << "Error";

    }
    else
    {
        if(!domDoc.setContent(&XMLfile))
        {
            qDebug() << "err";
        }
        XMLfile.close();
    }
    QDomElement root = domDoc.firstChildElement();

    //TrNode(root, "tRequestResponse");
    QDomNodeList tags = root.elementsByTagName("tRequestResponse");
    for (int i=0; i < tags.count(); i++)
    {
        QDomNode tagsnode = tags.at(i);
        if(tagsnode.isElement())
        {
            QDomElement tag = tagsnode.toElement();
            //TrNode(tag, "Response");
            qDebug() << "elem is: " << tag.text();
            //ui->lineEdit->setText("1");

        }
    }

    QString str = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 QDomNodeList list = domDoc.elementsByTagName("tRequestResponse");
 QDomElement second_treq = list.at(1).toElement();
 QDomElement resp_in_second = second_treq.firstChildElement("Response");
```

**resp_in_second** и будет **Response** элемент второго **tRequestResponse** элемента